# How do i have optional parameter but still validate them in asp.net mvc routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have this route that i just added

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "MyRoute",
            "MyController/{action}/{orgId}/{startDate}/{endDate}",
            new
                {
                    controller = "MyController",
                    action = "MyAction",
                    orgId = 0,
                    startDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1),
                    endDate = DateTime.Today
                },
            new
            {
                action = new FromValuesListConstraint(new string[] { "MyAction", "MyActionEx" }),
                orgId = new IntegerRouteConstraint(),
                startDate = new DateTimeRouteConstraint(),
                endDate = new DateTimeRouteConstraint()
            }
```

when i put in this url, it resolves down to the default route (controller, action,id) and the above rout does not catch this url:

```
http://localhost:1713/MyController/MyAction/16
```

But this below works fine.

```
http://localhost:1713/MyController/MyAction/16/11-May-10/11-May-10
```

my question is that i thought both would work as i am giving default values to the startDate and enddate fields

i tested this using [the RouteDebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) and this route turned up false

how can i have these last two parameter as optional but still have the validation ?

Comment: The order of routing is very important. Does this come before default route or after?

Comment: @Aliostad - it comes above the default route in the file (i am not sure if thats before or after ). And the routedebugger has it resolving as FALSE, so even if the order was reversed, it still is not finding a match

Comment: I thought so. Your format currently requires 5-part URL. see my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this in this current format does not fit to your route (requires 5-part URL).
You may change this line

```
      startDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1),
      endDate = DateTime.Today
```

to

```
      startDate = UrlParameter.Optional,
      endDate = UrlParameter.Optional
```

And do the conversion and defaults in the controller itself.

Comment: the problem here is that this will work IF I remove my Routing constraints around these fields (the DateTimeRouteConstraint constraint).  Is there any to have the constraint and the optional argument.  kind of like constrain if there ??

Comment: i DID try.  if i keep my constraints then it still doesn't resolve.  If i remove those constraint, then it DOES works but it also allows this:  http://localhost:1713/MyController/MyAction/16/1/abcd because of the lack of validation on the date field parameters

Comment: I see my friend. Sorry - cannot think of anything ekse. Happy to delete the answer if you want.

Comment: no, if there is no workaround, you answer is correct then. I gave an upvote

Answer (score 0):

You could follow @Aliostad's method and then write your own action filter attribute to validate the parameters that are coming into the method.  If they don't validate against your constraints then reject the url as you would normally.

```
public class ValidateParameterFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        bool areParametersValid = true;

        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("startDate"))
        {
            DateTime startDate;

            if (!DateTime.TryParse(filterContext.ActionParameters["startDate"].ToString(), out startDate))
            {
                // Not a DateTime so bad data in here
                areParametersValid = false;
            }
        }

        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("endDate"))
        {
            DateTime endDate;

            if (!DateTime.TryParse(filterContext.ActionParameters["endDate"].ToString(), out endDate))
            {
                // Not a DateTime so bad data in here
                areParametersValid = false;
            }
        }

        if (!areParametersValid)
        {
            // Redirect to error page or throw an exception
        }
}
```

Then on your action just decorate it with the attribute

```
[ValidateParameterFilter]
public ActionResult MyAction (int orgId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
...
}
```

Although I thought if you had the type declared as DateTime then an abc value would get rejected.